# How do I simplify this inequality equation to describe a hyperbola?

Tags: inequality

I have worked out my solutions until this point.

$$\sqrt{σ_1^2+σ_2^2 }=
\sqrt{[0.2×0.3\sqrt{(x+2000)^2+y^2}]^2+[0.2×(800+0.3\sqrt{(x-2000)^2+y^2} )]^2 }$$
$$c_1-c_2=
0.3\sqrt{((x+2000)^2+y^2 }-800-0.3\sqrt{(x-2000)^2+y^2 )}$$
The problem is to simplify this inequality:
$$c_1-c_2 \ge(0.2)\sqrt{σ_1^2+σ_2^2} $$

into this:
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}≥1$$
How do I solve this?
Would appreciate if someone can point me to the right direction. THANKS!

Comment: Does this come from a portfolio selection problem with two assets?

Comment: This is a transportation problem with selection of two route choices.

Comment: It works out pretty much the same as your [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2191328/how-do-i-simplify-this-inequality-equation-into-hyperbola-equation) - square until you eliminate the radicals, collect and cancel out along the way.